# Firebase: removing events from all children nodes (bookmark system)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to have a **live bookmark** count in my app. So, for each item, I set up a new firebase listener for its bookmark count:

```
ref.child('bookmark-count').child(ref).on('value', function(){ ... });
```

I run this for each item (with its own ref) that is currently in the view.

Now when the user leaves this view, I want to disconnect all the syncs. 
I thought doing

```
ref.off()
```

would do the trick, but it doesn't. However, with more specificity:

```
ref.child('bookmark-count').child(ref).off();
```

This works as expected.

I'm not keeping track of all the bookmarks I am synching as the user scrolls.  Is there a quick way to kill all events under the firebase node including its children?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly there is no easy way to do this. Firebase doens't remove listeners of child nodes as shown in [Unlink listener for parent does it applied to children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875824/unlink-listener-for-parent-does-it-applied-to-children-in-firebase)

My suggesting would be to keep track of all your listeners so you can remove them accordingly. And are all those listeners necessary or is there a way for you to improve on your current design? If you show your code im happy to have a look.

Comment: Thanks André. So I will keep track of the listeners. Another (seemingly bad) option would be to only listen to the parent node and ALL the bookmark events, which could have the potential to fire constantly, as users are toggling bookmarks. So I am thinking of only syncing the items in the view (components that have mounted as I'm using React and Flux). When the list component unmounts, I don't want to keep track of any bookmark counts anymore. Happy to improve on this design if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I think it all depends on the actual purpose of the listeners. And i have to say simply answering questions is a lot easyer than giving advice with limited info :)