# Life Cylcle of Controller Objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Hybrid app written in Ionic-1 that uses Angular-1 javascript library and HTML-5 to create hybrid apps.

In my code I am connecting to Firebase to fetch some data:

MyCtrl:

```
angular.module('myctrl.controller', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function () {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      try {
            var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users/" + loggedInUser.userName + "/details");             
            userRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
              var newUser = snapshot.val();
              console.log("New user " + JSON.stringify(newUser));
          });
        }
     });
  });
```

Now as I understand that controllers are re-instantiated every time views they are attached to are re-created. However, in my app even if I am outside the view which is attached to this controller, and add a user in firebase, this code gets executed. It confuses me as this code should have been garbage collected once view is replaced by another one. Does it mean that this `on()` method somehow getting attached to `$rooScope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase events won't got deregistered automatically, you have to unregister it manually when leaving controller.

```
var userRef;
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  try {
    userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users/" + loggedInUser.userName + "/details");             
    userRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
      var newUser = snapshot.val();
      console.log("New user " + JSON.stringify(newUser));
    });
  }
});

$scope.$on('destroy', function() {
  if (userRef) userRef.off();
})
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your ans. Do you know conceptually how does this `userRef` survives even when controller is destroyed? Shouldn't it be gone like any other variable that we define inside a controller?

Comment: @Richeek nope, this is not about `userRef` variable, when you call `userRef.on`, it will add a task to your browser's scheduler which won't be recycled unless you manually release it.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me some peace of mind :)  I tried looking for on() method docs earlier, but all I could find is jQuery on() method [https://api.jquery.com/on/] . Is it the same? May I ask if there are any docs where I can learn how these event handlers work?

Comment: @Richeek see documentation here.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

Comment: @Richeek also this post will help. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875824/unlink-listener-for-parent-does-it-applied-to-children-in-firebase

Comment: Just did! Do you know how lifecycle of database ref is handled? I do not find any mention of browser scheduler so I am kinda fail to understand how do these events survive?

Comment: @Richeek see whether these make any sense. https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-single-thread-handle-asynchronous-code-in-JavaScript  https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: Yeah make sense! Thanks.